# How to find a Javascript function if it is event handler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want use Chrome developer tool to add a break point to js function to debug it.

For example, a function "buttonAlert()" is binded to a button.

But I don't know where the code of such function, and I don't know where the code that bind the function to button.

So, how can I use the tool to find out the location of function and binding code?

Comment: Try looking at the function's *this*, which might be the related DOM object which might have an ID or other attribute that you can use to track down which one it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually possible to see event listeners in chrome.
Go to the elements panel, select the element in question and click on Event Listeners on the right side.

[image: Event Listeners panel]

Sadly most of the time when jQuery is in use, you only see the part of the source of jQuery that bound the event, not the one that called jQuery.